# Compare between two dates retrieved from database

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to compare between two dates that are situated in a two td and change the CSS of the row according to the result of the comparison.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var value1 = $('.eval1').text();
    var value2 =  $('.eval2').text();
    var trr=$('.eval1').closest('tr');
    var parts =value1.split('-');
    var mydate1 = new Date(parts[0], parts[1] - 1, parts[2]);
    console.log(mydate1);
    var parts =value2.split('-');
    var mydate2 = new Date(parts[0], parts[1] - 1, parts[2]);
    console.log(mydate2);
    if( mydate1 < mydate2 ) {
        trr.css('background-color', '#F44336').css('opacity', '0.5').css('color', 'black');

    }
});
```

the output of my console is like that :

**Sun Nov 17 2735 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale)

Sun Jan 13 2380 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale)**

but the year is wrong because the date I'm retrieving are :  2018-08-13 and 2018-07-26.

can you help solving this.

**edit**
[image: Dates to compare]

**edit2:**

the result of `console.log(value1)` and `console.log(value2)`

```
2018-07-262018-07-262018-07-262018-07-262018-07-262018-07-262018-07-262018-07-262018-07-262018-07-26
2018-08-132018-08-132018-08-132018-08-132018-08-132018-08-132018-08-132018-08-132018-08-132018-08-13
```

**edit3**

```
    @foreach($CommandesDomi as $Commande)
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>{{$Commande->NUM_CHASSIS_NADIN}}</td>
                                                <td>{{$Commande->CodeMarque}}</td>
                                                <td>{{$Commande->CodeModele}}</td>
                                                <td>{{$Commande->CodeFinition}}</td>
                                                <td>{{$Commande->Date_embarquement}}</td>
                                                <td class="eval2">{{$Commande->date_arrivage_oran}}</td>
                                                <td class="eval1">{{$Commande->data_dom}}</td>


                                            </tr>
                                         @endforeach
```

Comment: console.log value1 and value2 please

Comment: Try `var mydate1 = new Date(Date.parse(value1));`

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Sun Nov 17 2735 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale) Sun Jan 13 2380 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale)

Comment: Then the date you're retrieving is not what you say it is. As you can see, it's 2735 and 2380. Try to debug by going further up, see where `$('.eval2').text()` are coming from, output them, and keep going up till you find the source of the problem

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I've edited the post with what i'm retrieving

Comment: Please don't share an image, share the code creating that image.

Comment: I'm retrieving the data from my database using a simple query and the dates are stored in the same format in my database

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I've edited the post with the result of `console.log(value1)` and `console.log(value2)`

Comment: I see a lot more there than what you say is there. A dozen dates in each `value`...?

Comment: What's with all of these dates in the same value? Your question is becoming way more ambiguous.

Comment: No it's just one Date in each td but i'm doing the control on all the table and in the first page all the dates are the same for all the row so i guess that's why there's multiple dates

Comment: I'm guessing that `$('.eval1')` returns more than 1 element. And then you'll get the `text()` of all of them **together**.

Comment: I guess it should be iterative so I could controle all the value in the td that belongs to eval1.. I'll edit the post and add the html code

Comment: @PeterB I added `$('.eval1').each(function()` and it's true that `$('.eval1').text()` return multiple element but why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,instead of  parts[2] please use parts[2].substring(0,2),parts[2] giving date 262018 like this, this is invalid date,that's why you are getting error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var value1 = $('.eval1').text();
    var value2 =  $('.eval2').text();
    var trr=$('.eval1').closest('tr');
    var parts =value1.split('-');
    var mydate1 = new Date(parts[0], parts[1] - 1, parts[2].substring(0,2));
    console.log(mydate1);
    var parts =value2.split('-');
    var mydate2 = new Date(parts[0], parts[1] - 1, parts[2].substring(0,2));
    console.log(mydate2);
    if( mydate1 < mydate2 ) {
        trr.css('background-color', '#F44336').css('opacity', '0.5').css('color', 'black');

    }
});
```

Comment: it prints : invalid date

Comment: i was tried new Date('2018-08-13') --->Mon Aug 13 2018 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) and new Date('2018-07-26') --->Thu Jul 26 2018 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), your value1 and value2 exactly same as '2018-08-13' ,'2018-07-26'' or not??

Comment: No, the value1 and value2 are retrieving eval1 and eval2 many times like this `value1 : 2018-07-262018-07-262018-07-262018-07-262018-07-262018-07-262018-07-262018-07-262018-07-262018-07-26 value2:
2018-08-132018-08-132018-08-132018-08-132018-08-132018-08-132018-08-132018-08-132018-08-132018-08-13`

Comment: can you please provide value1 values and value2 values individually for better understanding.you are extracting with class ,many input fields have same class,i think thats why it extracting all field values.

Comment: in edit, we find the real value of value1 and value2 in my td and in edit2, we find what i'm getting from `console.log`

Comment: please check it once.

Comment: what should i check ?

Comment: in your code just add parts[2].substring(0,2) insted of parts[2], part[2] giveing '262018"'

Comment: in above i was written answer,please chek it.